# Mozilla Firefox hangs in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, firefox

I have recently upgraded my system from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. In the beginning everything was fine. It has been happening from 2-3 days that whenever I play any video on youtube, mozilla firefox hangs for 5 seconds, then responds for a second and then hangs once again so that I have to force close the browser. Any solutions to this problem?

```
$lscpu
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 42
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               2501.000
BogoMIPS:              4989.08
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try this in terminal and see if it fixes it

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

If not Try the following commands in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge firefox ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

This unistalls Firefox and the flash plugin you can then reinstall them and see if it works

```
sudo apt-get install firefox ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, still freezing. Btw first command you meant `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: You recommend uninstalling something and reinstalling it again. As a more complete answer, it would be useful to know how exactly this fixes the problem and what causes the problem in the first place.